# Can someone please critique my Factory Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, c#-4.0

I have recently been learning more about design patterns and thought I'd take a crack at it. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to use the factory pattern and was wondering if someone could provide me with feedback?

I basically have a set of calendar items that are similar. Meals, workouts and measurements. They all have a date and a name and can print details. but other than that they have a few items they each need differently.

```
    public enum AppointmentType
{
    Workout,
    Meal,
    Measurement
}

public abstract class Appointment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; }

    public virtual string PrintDetails()
    {
        return string.Format("Type: {0}\nName: {1}\nDate: {2}",this.GetType().ToString(), Name, DateStarted.ToShortDateString());
    }
}

public class Workout : Appointment
{
    public List<string> Exercises { get; set; }

    public Workout()
    {
        Exercises = new List<string>();
    }

    public override string PrintDetails()
    {
        string startInfo = base.PrintDetails();
        string addedInfo = "\nToday I will be doing the following:\n";

        foreach (string exercise in Exercises)
        {
            addedInfo += string.Format("{0}\n", exercise);
        }

        return startInfo + addedInfo;
    }
}

public class Meal : Appointment
{
    public List<string> FoodItems { get; set; }

    public Meal()
    {
        FoodItems = new List<string>();
    }

    public override string PrintDetails()
    {
        string startInfo = base.PrintDetails();
        string addedInfo = "\nToday I will be eating the following:\n";

        foreach (string foodItem in FoodItems)
        {
            addedInfo += string.Format("{0}\n", foodItem);
        }

        return startInfo + addedInfo;
    }
}

public class Measurement : Appointment
{
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }

    public override string PrintDetails()
    {
        string startInfo = base.PrintDetails();
        string addedInfo = string.Format("\nI am {0} feet tall and I weight {1} pounds!\n", Height, Weight);
        return startInfo + addedInfo;
    }
}

public interface IAppointmentFactory
{
    Appointment CreateAppointment(AppointmentType appointmentType);
}

public class AppointmentFactory : IAppointmentFactory
{
    public Appointment CreateAppointment(AppointmentType appointmentType)
    {
        switch (appointmentType)
        {
            case AppointmentType.Workout:
                return new Workout();
            case AppointmentType.Meal:
                return new Meal();
            case AppointmentType.Measurement:
                return new Measurement();
            default:
                return new Workout();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is a program using the library:

```
  class Program
{
    public static List<Appointment> myAppointments;
    public static AppointmentFactory factory;
    public static Appointment myAppointment;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myAppointments = new List<Appointment>();
        factory = new AppointmentFactory();
        StartLoop();
    }

    private static void StartLoop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\nWelcome to Appointment App: You have {0} appointment(s)!", myAppointments.Count()));
        Console.WriteLine("0 = Exit");
        Console.WriteLine("1 = New Workout");
        Console.WriteLine("2 = New Meal");
        Console.WriteLine("3 = New Measurement");
        Console.WriteLine("P = Print Schedule\n");

        switch (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper())
        {
            case "0":
                return;
            case "1":
                CreateNewAppointment(AppointmentType.Workout);
                AddExercises();
                break;
            case "2":
                CreateNewAppointment(AppointmentType.Meal);
                AddFoodItems();
                break;
            case "3":
                CreateNewAppointment(AppointmentType.Measurement);
                GetMeasurements();
                break;
            case "P":
                PrintSchedule();
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        StartLoop();
    }

    private static void GetMeasurements()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How tall are you?");
        ((Measurement)myAppointment).Height = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("What is your weight?");
        ((Measurement)myAppointment).Weight = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void AddFoodItems()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many food items do you want to add?");
        string exerciseCount = Console.ReadLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(exerciseCount); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Food {0}:", (i + 1)));
            ((Meal)myAppointment).FoodItems.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    private static void AddExercises()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many exercises do you want to add?");
        string exerciseCount = Console.ReadLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(exerciseCount); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exercise {0}:", (i + 1)));
            ((Workout)myAppointment).Exercises.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    private static void PrintSchedule()
    {
        foreach (Appointment appointment in myAppointments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(appointment.PrintDetails());
        }
    }

    public static void CreateNewAppointment(AppointmentType appointmentType)
    {
        myAppointment = factory.CreateAppointment(appointmentType);

        Console.WriteLine("Name:");
        myAppointment.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Start Date:");
        myAppointment.Name = Console.ReadLine();

        myAppointments.Add(myAppointment);
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

-ajax

Comment: in StartLoop, you'd be better served with a do-while instead of callign itself: Sufficiently long use of the application will cause an overflow.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not really wanting to use this library in a console app, but just wanted to throw something together that someone could quickly copy and paste into VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would change it to:

```
public enum AppointmentType
{
    Workout,
    Meal,
    Measurement
}

public abstract class Appointment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; }

    public abstract void PrintDetails();
    public abstract void RequestInputFromUser();
}

public class Workout : Appointment
{
    private List<string> Exercises { get; set; }

    public Workout()
    {
        Exercises = new List<string>();
    }

    public override void PrintDetails()
    {
        string startInfo = base.PrintDetails();
        string addedInfo = "\nToday I will be doing the following:\n";

        foreach (string exercise in Exercises)
        {
            addedInfo += string.Format("{0}\n", exercise);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(StartInfo + addedInfo);
    }

    public override void RequestInputFromUser()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many exercises do you want to add?");
        string exerciseCount = Console.ReadLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(exerciseCount); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exercise {0}:", (i + 1)));
            Exercises.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}

public class Meal : Appointment
{
    private List<string> FoodItems { get; set; }

    public Meal()
    {
        FoodItems = new List<string>();
    }

    public override void PrintDetails()
    {
        string startInfo = base.PrintDetails();
        string addedInfo = "\nToday I will be eating the following:\n";

        foreach (string foodItem in FoodItems)
        {
            addedInfo += string.Format("{0}\n", foodItem);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(startInfo + addedInfo);
    }

    public override void RequestInputFromUser()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many food items do you want to add?");
        string exerciseCount = Console.ReadLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(exerciseCount); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Food {0}:", (i + 1)));
            FoodItems.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}

public class Measurement : Appointment
{
    private string Height { get; set; }
    private string Weight { get; set; }

    public override void PrintDetails()
    {
        string startInfo = base.PrintDetails();
        string addedInfo = string.Format("\nI am {0} feet tall and I weight {1} pounds!\n", Height, Weight);
        Console.WriteLine(startInfo + addedInfo);
    }

    public override void RequestInputFromUser()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How tall are you?");
        Height = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("What is your weight?");
        Weight = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface IAppointmentFactory
{
    Appointment CreateAppointment(AppointmentType appointmentType);
}

public class AppointmentFactory : IAppointmentFactory
{
    public Appointment CreateAppointment(AppointmentType appointmentType)
    {
        Appointment apt;

        switch (appointmentType)
        {
            case AppointmentType.Workout:
                apt = new Workout();
            case AppointmentType.Meal:
                apt = new Meal();
            case AppointmentType.Measurement:
                apt = new Measurement();
            default:
                apt = new Workout();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Name:");
        apt.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Start Date:");
        apt.Name = Console.ReadLine();    // Logic error on this line.
                                          // Change it to do what you mean.

        apt.RequestInputFromUser();

        return apt;
    }
}
```

with the code using it as follows:

```
class Program
{
    public static List<Appointment> myAppointments;
    public static AppointmentFactory factory;
    public static Appointment myAppointment;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myAppointments = new List<Appointment>();
        factory = new AppointmentFactory();
        StartLoop(factory);
    }

    private static void StartLoop(IAppointmentFactory factory)
    {
        bool exit = false;

        while(!exit)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\nWelcome to Appointment App: You have {0} appointment(s)!", myAppointments.Count()));
            Console.WriteLine("0 = Exit");
            Console.WriteLine("1 = New Workout");
            Console.WriteLine("2 = New Meal");
            Console.WriteLine("3 = New Measurement");
            Console.WriteLine("P = Print Schedule\n");

            switch (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper())
            {
                case "0":
                    exit = true;
                    break;
                case "1":
                    myAppointments.Add( factory.CreateAppointment( AppointmentType.Workout ) );
                    break;
                case "2":
                    myAppointments.Add( factory.CreateAppointment( AppointmentType.Meal ) );
                    break;
                case "3":
                    myAppointments.Add( factory.CreateAppointment( AppointmentType.Measurement ) );
                    break;
                case "P":
                    PrintSchedule();
                    break;
                default:
                    exit = true;
            }

        }

    }

    private static void PrintSchedule()
    {
        foreach (Appointment appointment in myAppointments)
        {
            appointment.PrintDetails();
        }
    }

}
```

A couple things to notice:

- All properties in the lower classes are private (a good thing)
- There is no type casting (another good thing)
- It is easy to add another Appointment type (another good thing)

There are still things that can change. The base class having public properties is still a bad thing. But this is a large improvement.

I also removed the recursive call to StartLoop(). You don't want to grow the stack when all you need is a loop.

EDIT: Made some more changes to the Factory class.

In response to comments:

- To remove the dependency on the Console, create an interface that represents what you want to do with IO. Create classes that implement this interface and send an instance to the Appointment class. From there, have everything use the instance of the IO engine. To change the platform, change the IO-implementing class that is sent to the Appointment class
- Public properties are bad for the same reason that public variables are bad. A class should hide its implementation, and public properties expose the implementation. For more detail, I suggest [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882). It describes it much better than I can.

Overall, not bad :)

Comment: Thanks! I really like how you've motified the classes :)

My main goal is to start of simple with these basic patterns and to to understand where I can use them. I've been trying for years to write a calendar website for myself (of which there are 100s out there already, but I want to make my own ;)) 

Very useful info, thanks!

Comment: Glad you like it. One more thing that I forgot to mention--notice how much smaller the code is that uses the library. This is a very useful way to design your classes, and usually increases your productivity.

Comment: This library won't really be made for a console app, my original idea is to have a web service of different functions that a client can call(droid, iphone, windows phone, Silverlight, asp.net...etc) so having Console.ReadLine(); in the classes wouldn't work. How coudl this be best modied for this??

Comment: One more quick thing, why is it bad to have public props??? I'm a bit confused by this. THanks, you rock for helping me :D

Comment: Answered in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the abstract factory pattern is used when you need to create different sets of the same kinds of objects. So, for instance, you might have a factory which vends

```
Supersize-Workout
Supersize-Meal
Supersize-Measurement
```

and another which vends

```
Mini-Workout
Mini-Meal
Mini-Measurement
```

These factory classes could then be fed to a system which needs to create workouts, meals and measurements but doesn't care if they are supersize or mini, as long as they're all the same.

In the absence of a second factory, I find your abstract factory a bit odd.

Comment: Looks like the OP is using just a straight Factory Method rather than an Abstract Factory.  The lack of object families (like your examples of Supersize and Mini) are evidence of this.

Comment: @kevinmajor1: I was going to say the same thing, but having the IAppointmentFactory is an indication of an abstract factory (in this case, without another factory to create additional appointments).

Comment: I'm a bit confused, should I be using an Abstract Factory for something like this? I was going for just the straight up simpple factory method...

Comment: What you've done then is use the abstract factory pattern to implement a simple factory method. Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters - you code follows the pattern nicely.

Your particular implementation suffers from a few issues (nothing that cannot be worked around though):

1. Using an enum for the parameter violates the [OCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) principle. If you add or worse yet, remove a value to/from the enum, clients will have to recompile to use the correct (new) enum. For the textbook answer - you could use a string to represent the type you want to create and then throw exceptions/handle it in some other way when a non-supported type is requested.
2. Adding a new Factory-implementation will be forced to only support the same return types as the original factory can handle - unless you can re-compile (violating OCP again). Depending on your scenario - this might be okay.

But other than that - in my oppinion it is a viable implementation.